# Преобразование Double к DateTime

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, есть бинарный файл с которого я читаю значения файла, и мне нужно преобразовать с doube в DateTime, сам бинарник формируется пока на C++ Builder, позже будет переписан...

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
{
    // пока не достигнут конец файла
    // считываем каждое значение из файла
    while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
    {
        double t_n = reader.ReadDouble();
        double t_k = reader.ReadDouble();
        var time = Convert.ToDateTime(t_n);
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Недопустимое приведение "Double" к "DateTime".
>   Пробовал еще так :

```
var tn_n = DateTime.FromOADate(t_n);
```

Получаю ошибку :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Не является допустимой датой OleAut.

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вопрос в том, как эта дата была преобразована в `double` во время записи.

Comment: @VladD В исходниках на Buildere переменные:`TDateTime t_n;
TDateTime t_k;` а далее в коде : `StringGrid16->Cells[i+1][1]=
        FormatDateTime("d.mm.yy' / 'h:mm",(per[j].t_n));` К сожалению это максимум что я могу сейчас вам предоставить, потому как у меня сейчас только программа на Buildere которая тоже занимается чтением. Просто исходя из выше сказанного я подумал что DateTime подойдет

Comment: Этот код форматирует `TDateTime` и выдаёт его в таблицу, а интересно, как он записывается в файл.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за ответ, завтра гляну, и отпишусь. Еще раз спасибо за ваше время

Comment: еще неплохо бы получить образец содержимого double и как оно выглядит (должно выглядеть) на выходе, для экспериментов

Comment: Если там OLE время попробуйте `DateTime.FromOADate()` [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @VladD  `UnicodeString DT; TDateTime dtPresent = Now();Ns = AnsiString(DT).c_str(); ser = CreateFile(Ns, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, &Attr1, OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);` Как-то так ...

Comment: @Ethernets: Это уже близко, но всё равно пока непонятно, как записывается `dtPresent` в файл.

Comment: @VladD Доброго времени суток хотел бы возобновить тему. Дело в то что я не могу точно сказать как данные записываются в dtPresent. Вот например кусок кода на С++ `AnsiString dt=FormatDateTime("d.mm.yy'  'hh:mm:ss'  '",(sr.ts))` тут видно как происходит преобразование к нужному формату. Если посмотреть при отладке то - видно что `sr.ts = 4181.303765` такому же числу равна и запись в VS при отладке

Comment: @Ethernets: Ага, это уже теплее. А какого типа `sr`?

Comment: @Ethernets: Ага, это `TDateTime`. Судя по всему, `DateTime.FromOADate` [должно быть правильно](http://ideone.com/aYIJaS). А на каком значении вылетает исключение? Какое при этом значение `TDateTime`?

Comment: @VladD `sr` это структура. Большое спасибо за помощь я уже разобрался, и сделал. Большое вам спасибо.Единственное на что могу грешить это только на то что так делать нельзя : `var tn_n = DateTime.FromOADate(t_n);` а нужно сначала обьявить тип переменной а потом вызвать и присвоить.

Comment: @Ethernets: Хм, разницы быть не должно по идее. Ну ладно, может быть исправление в другой части программы исправило эту часть.

Comment: @VladD Возможно, потому как до этого был не правильный вызов union и возможно смещение давало не те данные, на которые я сразу не обратил внимание. Спасибо

Comment: Окей, тогда напишу как ответ, чтобы будущие поколения смогли найти информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расследование в комментариях показало, что исходное значение в C++ Builder имело тип [`TDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.TDateTime).

`TDateTime` хранит время в формате OLE Automation date, так что правильно конвертировать при помощи [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Обратите внимание, что не всякое значение `double` является валидным значением для `TDateTime`, поэтому если при чтении у вас прочиталось неверное значение `double`, конвертация может выбросить исключение.